# [__NSArrayI count]: message sent to deallocated instance iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, instance, allocation

I have a method that draws scatter plots and I get the error [__NSArrayI count]: message sent to deallocated instance.

I made a debug and the error is at the line

```
   [plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:aaplPlot, googPlot, msftPlot, nil]];
```

I think there is a problem with the objects getting released, but I don't know exactly how to solve the problem. I get the error when the method gets called the second time.

This is the method:

```
-(void)configurePlots {

    // 1 - Get graph and plot space
    CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    // 2 - Create the three plots
    CPTScatterPlot *aaplPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    aaplPlot.dataSource = self;
    aaplPlot.identifier = CPDTickerSymbolAAPL;
    CPTColor *aaplColor = [CPTColor redColor];
    [graph addPlot:aaplPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];
    CPTScatterPlot *googPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    googPlot.dataSource = self;
    googPlot.identifier = CPDTickerSymbolGOOG;
    CPTColor *googColor = [CPTColor greenColor];
    [graph addPlot:googPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];
    CPTScatterPlot *msftPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    msftPlot.dataSource = self;
    msftPlot.identifier = CPDTickerSymbolMSFT;
    CPTColor *msftColor = [CPTColor blueColor];
    [graph addPlot:msftPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];
    // 3 - Set up plot space
    // Here is the problem//
    [plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:aaplPlot, googPlot, msftPlot, nil]];
    CPTMutablePlotRange *xRange = [plotSpace.xRange mutableCopy];
    [xRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(1.1f)];
    plotSpace.xRange = xRange;
    CPTMutablePlotRange *yRange = [plotSpace.yRange mutableCopy];
    [yRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(1.2f)];
    plotSpace.yRange = yRange;
    // 4 - Create styles and symbols
    CPTMutableLineStyle *aaplLineStyle = [aaplPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
    aaplLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.5;
    aaplLineStyle.lineColor = aaplColor;
    aaplPlot.dataLineStyle = aaplLineStyle;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *aaplSymbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    aaplSymbolLineStyle.lineColor = aaplColor;
    CPTPlotSymbol *aaplSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
    aaplSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:aaplColor];
    aaplSymbol.lineStyle = aaplSymbolLineStyle;
    aaplSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(6.0f, 6.0f);
    aaplPlot.plotSymbol = aaplSymbol;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *googLineStyle = [googPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
    googLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0;
    googLineStyle.lineColor = googColor;
    googPlot.dataLineStyle = googLineStyle;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *googSymbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    googSymbolLineStyle.lineColor = googColor;
    CPTPlotSymbol *googSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol starPlotSymbol];
    googSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:googColor];
    googSymbol.lineStyle = googSymbolLineStyle;
    googSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(6.0f, 6.0f);
    googPlot.plotSymbol = googSymbol;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *msftLineStyle = [msftPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
    msftLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0;
    msftLineStyle.lineColor = msftColor;
    msftPlot.dataLineStyle = msftLineStyle;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *msftSymbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    msftSymbolLineStyle.lineColor = msftColor;
    CPTPlotSymbol *msftSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol diamondPlotSymbol];
    msftSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:msftColor];
    msftSymbol.lineStyle = msftSymbolLineStyle;
    msftSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(6.0f, 6.0f);
    msftPlot.plotSymbol = msftSymbol;
}
```

I made a few changes: I made graph, plotSpace, array, aaplPlot, googPlot and msftPlot properties and I allocate and initialize array with the scatterplots.

```
  array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:aaplPlot, googPlot, msftPlot, nil];
  [plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:array];
```

I get the same error, when the method gets called the second time.

Comment: Make sure your objects are not nil since you are saying this only occurs on the 2nd run. Place a breakpoint right before the crash then check the graph and other objects. I believe you will find the answer after doing this. Also, are you using ARC? A guess would be that plotSpace is nil and not the new array. Is graph.defaultPlotSpace nil?

Comment: The NSArray is autoreleased, retain it.

Comment: A response would make debugging this issue a lot easier. We can't post an accurate answer without a response. This is why I deleted my previous answer...

Answer (score 0):

self.hostView.hostedGraph is being released. Create this as a property with retain or strong values then check again. Since this happens on the 2nd run only it appears your object is being released since it's been used.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CPTGraph *graph;
```

Comment: @giorashc I would imagine ARC releasing the array but making sure the count is correct prior to the next statement will make sure that's the issue.

Comment: than you should explain it in your answer. It seems like a guess more than an answer

Comment: But the array is generated "on the fly" so how can you check it ? the error is on the same line.

Comment: Set a breakpoint right after the NSArray *array to check the count

Comment: This is still will not 100% will help. You need to debug the line where this array is used inside the plotting class

Comment: Giorashc, either offer your answer or please stop saying this will not help... Contribute, don't chastise. Setting a breakpoint right after initializing the array is the exact same thing you just said... Place the breakpoint on the [plotspace scaleToFitPlots:array]; Check the count of the array by hovering over the array or type "po array" in the console.

Comment: @MarkM, Your answer should be a comment for the following reasons : You do not know what is the source of the problem. You started your answer with the word "try" which looks more like you are guessing than knowing if it will be solved or not. And I would have answered it if I knew what the problem was.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20883/discussion-between-markm-and-giorashc)

Comment: Hey! I'm sorry I couldn't answer your questions yesterday, but I had a problem. I debugged the line where array is located and the count is 3 every time. I made aaplPlot, googPlot, msftPlot, plotSpace, graph and array properties, but I have the same problem. The first time the method is called, the variables aaplPlot, googPlot, msftPlot have some values and the second time other values.

Comment: @MarkM when the code crashes at that line, nothing seems to be nil. :)  self BrowserViewController * 0x1107cbc0
msftColor CPTColor * 0x11043f70
aaplPlot CPTScatterPlot * 0x110969a0
array __NSArrayI * 0x0852e250
googPlot CPTScatterPlot * 0x11096b80
graph CPTXYGraph * 0x110943c0
msftPlot CPTScatterPlot * 0x11096d10
plotSpace CPTXYPlotSpace * 0x11093db0
CPDTickerSymbolMSFT NSString *const 0x000ccbbc

Comment: Try enabling NSZombie and see if you can get a more detailed crash report. Go to the Diagnostics tab of your current scheme and enable "Enable Zombie Objects". This should show you at what point something is dropping off and should clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

```
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
```

The above plotSpace is in a method, try making it as a static variable or class property so that it is not released, and check if it is again `init`-ed. in case of property.